# web3 trying to connect to the rinkeby testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, rinkeby

I've installed the `mist` wallet, connected the `rinkeby`testnet and transferred  3ETH to myself from the [faucet](https://faucet.rinkeby.io/)

[image]

`web3` is defined like so

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));
}
```

setup a meteor app and trying to show the balance using `web3`

```
  var my_test_address = "0x269999b8dC883628ed7EE7aaAdD498e50C164905";
  web3.eth.getBalance(my_test_address, 'latest',
    function (err, res){
      console.log('err');
      console.log(err);
      alert(res)
    }
    )
```

the alert shows `0`

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to mention that I was counting on `metamask` chrome extension to inject the web3 object to my project.

solved it by simply changing the network there

[image]